# Anchor tag working locally, but not when deployed

Tags: html, deployment, anchor, surge.sh

Weird problem I'm running into... This anchor tag
`<a target='_blank' href='jresume.pdf'>Resume</a>`
is working fine locally. Opens a new page and loads my pdf file.
But for some reason when I deploy my site to surge.sh the link no longer works and gives me this error "No webpage was found for the web address: http://sitename.surge.sh/jresume.pdf"
if anyone could help that'd be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first step I would take is to make sure the file is in the right place on your web server (have you actually uploaded the file to your web server?). I guess that'd be in the same folder as your index.html or the same folder as whatever html file is linking to it.

If that's not the problem I'd try changing `href='jresume.pdf'` to `href='./jresume.pdf'` and seeing if it makes a difference.